# How do I convert a string to object?

Tags: ruby, json

I'd like to convert the string:

```
"{\"message\":\"success\"}"
```

into:

```
{:message => "success"}
```

Is there an easy way to do that in Ruby?

`success` may not be a a simple string, but another string of the same form that may be another object.

Comment: Is your input just a JSON string?

Answer (score 4):

`JSON#parse` has an option to make symbols of the hash keys (strangely named "symbolize_names")

```
require 'json'
p some_hash = JSON.parse("{\"message\":\"success\"}", {:symbolize_names=>true})
#=> {:message=>"success"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a JSON parser. Look at http://www.json.org and find a suitable parser that will return the appropriate Ruby classes.

This looks like a good candidate: http://flori.github.com/json/

Also see 'mu is too short's' comment below about the [standard JSON Parser in the Ruby libraries](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html).

Comment: Ruby comes with a JSON parser in the standard library: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html

Comment: Ah, even better! Added above.

Answer (score -3):

Following may be any ugly approach, but just another way of doing it:

```
str=["{\"message\":\"success\"}", "{\"new_message\":\"fail\"}"] #=> ["{\"message\":\"success\"}", "{\"new_message\":\"fail\"}"]

new=[];str.each{|string| new<<string.gsub(/["{}]/,'').split(':')}
new #=> [["message", "success"], ["new_message", "fail"]]
new=new.transpose #=> => [["message", "new_message"], ["success", "fail"]]
hash=Hash.new #=> {}
new[0].each_with_index{|x,i| hash[x.to_sym]=new[1][i]} #=> ["message", "new_message"]
hash #=> {:message=>"success", :new_message=>"fail"}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Good luck

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : As I said, it is an ugly approach to do that :) .It will work well, until OP asked for, 'success may not be a a simple string, but another another string of the same form that may be another object'.