# how to convert string of object to object in rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, hash

How can I convert this string of object to just object.

// object inside string

```
"{\"text\"=>\"ID\", \"value\"=>\"id\"}"
```

// object

```
{"text"=>"ID", "value"=>"id"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468515/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-object)

Comment: Where does this string representation come from in the first place? You tagged your question as `json` but this is isn't JSON – it looks more like the output from `Hash#inspect`.

Comment: @Gandhi I tried what is suggested in question but it returns: JSON::ParserError: 765: unexpected token at ‘{“text”=>“ID”, “value”=>“id”}’

Comment: Where did you get this string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pure Ruby option using `scan` along with a `regex` and `to_h`.
**NOTE:** This solution assumes all keys and values are strings:

```
string = "{\"text\"=>\"ID\", \"value\"=>\"id\"}"
string.scan(/"(.*?)"=>"(.*?)"/).to_h
#=>  {"text"=>"ID", "value"=>"id"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this

```rb
require 'json'

def string_parse_to_hash(string)
  modified_string = string
    .gsub(/:(\w+)/){"\"#{$1}\""}
    .gsub('=>', ':')
    .gsub("nil", "null")
  JSON.parse(modified_string)
rescue
  {}
end

str = "{\"text\"=>\"ID\", \"value\"=>\"id\"}"
puts string_parse_to_hash(str)
```

But be ware, if you don't trust the source of the string, you have to sanitize and validate its content.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to live dangerously, this is also an option:

```rb
str = "{\"text\"=>\"ID\", \"value\"=>\"id\"}"
parsed_hash = eval(str)
# {"text"=>"ID", "value"=>"id"}
```

but that is kinda very dangerous depending on where you get your input from.

`eval` literally evaluates your string as ruby code. So you could inject literally anything that would be very harmful

Comment: _"dangerously ... very dangerous ... very harmful"_ – then why even suggest it?

Comment: `eval` is evil. It's better to find another solution

Comment: @Stefan because technically it is an answer to the question . Being from the US (I can't speak for other countries), I use products every day that have warning labels longer than CVS receipts but they serve a purpose and I would recommend them to others as needed; however it is still paramount one understands the danger.

Comment: Also guys feel free to add another better answer, that's just how SO works

Comment: I'm not sure answer is needed at all because it is very strange to convert `hsh.to_s` to `hsh` back :)

Comment: `eval` is not evil. Evil is not knowing when to use the tools you were given at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is:

```
eval "{\"text\"=>\"ID\", \"value\"=>\"id\"}"
 => {"text"=>"ID", "value"=>"id"}
```

[Some doc that may help you understand eval in ruby](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/5-metaprogramming-ruby-ascent/chapters/24-eval/lessons/63-eval)

Answer (score -1):

You could use `JSON.parse` with a slight adjustment to the string you receive:

```
JSON.parse(my_string.gsub('=>', ':'))
```

where `my_string = "{\"text\"=>\"ID\", \"value\"=>\"id\"}"` in this case

#### Explanation

Thinking it backwards, by converting the object you expect to have with `.to_json` we have:

```
{"text"=>"ID", "value"=>"id"}.to_json
=>
"{\"text\":\"ID\",\"value\":\"id\"}"

"{\"text\"=>\"ID\", \"value\"=>\"id\"}" # my_string
```

Comparing it with the one you receive, you can see that the only difference between them is the `:` char instead of `=>` between key & value